# Geração de hash SHA256 de arquivos comprimidos em.zip

Tags: python, hash, arquivo-zip, sha-256

Gostaria de gerar uma hash com SHA256 de um conjunto de arquivos. Para isso comprimi todos em formato `.zip` e estou utilizando o seguinte código(Python):

```
from hashlib import sha256

myFile = 'path/to/my/file.zip'

with open(myFile,'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        hashedWord = sha256(line.rstrip()).hexdigest()

        print(hashedWord)
```

Queria saber se esse código está codificando todas as linhas de todos os meus arquivos no `.zip` ou se o método está incorreto

Comment: Você quer gerar o hash de forma separada para cada arquivo?

Comment: Oi @AndersonCarlosWoss, quero um hash unico para todos os arquivos contidos no zip

Comment: Então poderia explicar porque percorreu as linhas do arquivo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss utilizando apenas hashedWord = sha256(f).hexdigest() o código retorna erro(TypeError: object supporting the buffer API require). Então percorri todas as linhas, pois imaginei que se o arquivo zip é um conjunto de linhas que vai representar o conteúdo, o método de percorrer as linhas também estaria correto. Essa é a dúvida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a intenção é gerar o hash a partir do arquivo inteiro, basta ler o conteúdo dele:

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as stream:
    hash = hashlib.sha256(stream.read())

print(hash.hexdigest())
```

Como [comentado abaixo pelo jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401885/gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-hash-sha256-de-arquivos-comprimidos-em-zip/401888?noredirect=1#comment788512_401888), quando você itera sobre um arquivo aberto como binário você não iterará as linhas do arquivo, mas sim byte a byte, o que geraria um *overhead* desnecessário para a aplicação.

Comment: se o arquivo for aberto como binário e não como texto (necessário para um arquivo zip, e mais necessário ainda quando a intenção é gerar um hash), iterar o conteúdo do arquivo traz cada _byte_ de uma vez, e não cada "linha" (o que seria "linha" em arquivo zip, alias??). Usar um arquivo em modo binário  num "for" como no código da questão traz um overhead considerável.

Comment: @jsbueno Faz sentido, não parei para analisar isso. Obrigado

Comment: @jsbueno Lembra se tem alguma duplicada sobre isso? Cheguei a olhar, mas não encontrei.

Comment: não lembro de ter visto questões aqui sobre geração de hash não.